# SQL query in many-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many

I am struggling a problem described bellow.

Suppose there is a many-to-many relationship between students and classes, and middle table who explains which student enrolled which classes like the image.

[image]

[Referring from this site.](https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/help/18/fmp/en/index.html#page/FMP_Help/many-to-many-relationships.html)

I wrote a query script to get classes enrolled by the student who is corresponding to the given student id, such that

```
select c.Title, 
       c.Description 
from Enrollments as e 
inner join Students s on e.Student_ID = s.id 
inner join Classes c on e.Class_ID = c.id where Student_ID = ?;
```

However, I am struggling a problem to query the classes not enrolled by the student with given student id.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use exists logic here:

```sql
SELECT c.Title, c.Description
FROM Classes c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Enrollments e
    WHERE e.Class_ID = c.id AND e.Student_ID = ?
);
```